# Timer is resetting on refresh how to avoid that?

Tags: javascript, timer

this is my java-script code which is resetting on refreshing how to avoid that

```
 <script>
 //define your time in second
    var c=120;
    var t;
    timedCount();

    function timedCount()
    {

        var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
        var seconds = c % 60;

        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes <    10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);



       document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=result;


       if(c == 0 )
        {
            //setConfirmUnload(false);
            //$("#quiz_form").submit();
            window.location="result.php?td=$tid";
        }
        c = c - 1;
        t = setTimeout(function()
        {
         timedCount()
        },
        1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a page is readloaded, the entire context of the old page is destroyed and an entirely new context is created. You can't keep a timer from one page load running on the next page load.

If you need to save some state from one page load to the next and then in the next page load examine that state and decide exactly how to set up the initial page to match what was previously going on, then you can save state between page loads in either HTML5 local storage or in a cookie.

The other possibility is to NOT reload your page and instead update the contents of the page dynamically using ajax and javascript. That way your existing timer would just keep running because there would be no page reload at all.

If all you're trying to do with your timer is show how much time is left in some countdown, you can set the countdown zero time into HTML5 local storage and when the reloaded page loads, it can check the time set in local storage and start the countdown timer to match the time it was previously set for.

> Use cookie, or if HTML5 then local/session storage to save state.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="SaveTime()">Save Current Time</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="retrieveTime()">Retrieve Saved Time</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function SaveTime(){
var date = new Date();
var timeObj = { sec:date.getSeconds(), min:date.getMinutes(), hr:date.getHours() };
localStorage.setItem("timeObj", JSON.stringify(timeObj));
$('#result').append(JSON.stringify(timeObj)+' -- > Saved<br />' );
}

function retrieveTime(){
var timeObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeObj"));
//You have the time with you now
//You have the time with you now
$('#result').append(timeObj.hr+':'+timeObj.min+':'+timeObj.sec+' --> Retrieved<br />');
}
```

Its just a basic example to save timer in local storage on click. Modify it and call the javascript function in timer regularly.

Comment: if possible can you please give some line of code for saving timer in session. SO that i will get clear picture about that

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp best example to store and retrieve localstorage in HTML5

Comment: Is this answer solve the OP's problem ? Did you tried anything with the code? OP want a code solution. Not the details

Comment: Yeh exactly code will help me in much better way. means where should I make changes in above code.

Comment: Added basic JS code block to save and retrive timer in HTML5.

Comment: Answers merged now.

Comment: Still not getting brother. :(